# What is this code enhancement or practice called? (null == conn) as opposed to (conn == null)

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, terminology

I am trying to make a report of some code enhancement, however, i am not too sure what this item is called. Basically, instead of doing a `conn == null`, it does a `null == conn` for readability.

Before:

```
        if (conn == null){            
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()){
                log.debug("Failed to get a DB Connection");
            }
        }
```

After:

```
        if (null == conn){            
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()){
                log.debug("Failed to get a DB Connection");
            }
        }
```

Comment: it's no enhancement and both are semantically the same.

Comment: I wouldn't say that one is more readable than the other. They're equivalent in almost every way, and in every way that matters.

Comment: I have heard the term [Yoda Conditions](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/) used sometimes (at least on SO). Happy coding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not for readability, it's to prevent accidental assigning instead of comparing.

If you accidentally write:

```
if (conn = null)
```

in C or C++, that will set `conn` to `null` and then use that value as the condition. This has been carried over into Java despite the fact that it's not necessary there.

The other way around, the compiler catches it as an attempt to assign to a constant so it won't even compile.

As for what its called, I've never seen it given a specific name. You can call it what you want provided you explain it. I like `Accidental assignment avoidance` since I can just shorten that to `triple-a`.

Comment: Java only allows boolean expressions in `if` statements, so this can be only used for something like `if (true == someCondition)` in which case it's better to write `if (someCondition)` anyway

Comment: Of course, such an assignment in Java doesn't cast itself into a boolean, so it's more a tip of the hat to history than actually a precautionary measure.

Comment: Java will still accept `if (x = true)`, where x is a boolean variable. It will not accept `if (true = x)` (which is silly, but alas..). So this inverted conditional will still save you, even if there is no magical cast to boolean or whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

This practice is called "putting the constant before the variable in an equality test".

Ostensibly its purpose is to avoid the a specific kind of typing error:

```
if (conn = null) { ...
```

where the `=` is *assignment* (when `==` *comparison* was intended). Modern compilers warn about this error, so this practice is not really needed any more.

Comment: HiGreg, modern compiler, with reference to which?

Comment: I was mostly referring to old C compilers. This usually isn't a problem in Java, since the only type for which `if (conn = ____)` would work is if `conn` is a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

It is just to avoid assigning to a variable by mistake.

That is if you use `conn=null` then null is assigned to the variable, however, if you do `null=conn` then the compiler will through an error since you cannot assign to 'null'.

So it prevents errors where you mistakenly type one '=' instead of two '=='

Answer (score 0):

That particular syntax is quite useless. But consider when you are comparing an object with unknown initialization state to a 'constant' object.

```
String unknown;
String KNOWN = "Hello";
```

It is much better to do your comparison so:

```
if(KNOWN.equals(unknown)) do something;
```

As it saves a null check which if omitted could cause a runtime exception.